# Iterate through all the user setting for current application

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have an application that stores some setting specific to user.

I have created a settings class derived from ApplicationSettingsBase.

```
Public Class MySetting : ApplicationSettingsBase
```

This class have a property that specifies that this setting is specific to an application session.

At the time of application exit (Application.Current.Exit event), I want to iterate through all user settings and set all the <MySetting> type settings with default value. In that way these will be session specific.

For Example: A dialog by default opens at center of the screen. For current application session user moved it to top left of the screen. Now, if user closes the dialog and re-opens it, it will open at top left of the screen. But when he closes and re-launches the application the dialog again appears at the center of the screen.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Give more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (SettingsProperty property in Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: But I dont get anything in properties.

Comment: Properties or settings ? On your title you asked to iterate through all the settings. The above method does just that.